# Remove an attribute by its key from a jsonb array in a loop

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql, jsonb

I try to remove an attribute by its key from a jsonb array in a loop

```
groups = '
[
    {"id": "1", "name": "Ann", "age": 20 },
    {"id": "2", "name": "Margaret", "age": 30 }
]';

FOR i IN 0..(jsonb_array_length(groups) - 1)
LOOP
groups = groups - '{age}';
END LOOP;

/* but nothing happened, I see [{"id": "1", "age": 20, "name": "Ann"}, {"id": "2", "age": 30, "name": "Margaret"}] */

RAISE NOTICE '%', groups;
```

but nothing happened. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify only a single element of the array in each step of the loop, so you have to use a new variable to aggregate results:

```
do $$
declare 
    groups jsonb = 
    '[
        {"id": "1", "name": "Ann", "age": 20 },
        {"id": "2", "name": "Margaret", "age": 30 }
    ]';
    new_groups jsonb = '[]';
begin
    for i in 0..jsonb_array_length(groups) - 1
    loop
        new_groups:= new_groups || (groups->i) - 'age';
    end loop;
    raise notice '%', new_groups;
end $$;

NOTICE:  [{"id": "1", "name": "Ann"}, {"id": "2", "name": "Margaret"}]
DO
```

A better option is to do the same in a single query without a loop and an additional variable:

```
do $$
declare 
    groups jsonb = 
    '[
        {"id": "1", "name": "Ann", "age": 20 },
        {"id": "2", "name": "Margaret", "age": 30 }
    ]';
begin
    select jsonb_agg(value- 'age')
    from jsonb_array_elements(groups)
    into groups;
    raise notice '%', groups;
end $$;
```